# What is an advantage of using DDL objects as opposed to using SQL queries to create a new table?

Tags: magento2

Can anyone tell me the correct answer from these 4 options

```
  a. They allow setup scripts to be cross-database compatible with any underlying RDBMS.
  b. They do not require developers to have a knowledge of the underlying RDBMS.
  c. They are easier to use than SQL queries.
  d. They prevent module conflicts.
```

Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 5):

None of the answers are correct. The only one which kind of qualifies is option a.

> a. They allow setup scripts to be cross-database compatible with any underlying RDBMS.

This option would be true, except that Magento only supports MySQL, so in practice it is not a valid answer.

> b. They do not require developers to have a knowledge of the underlying RDBMS.

This option is not true because a developer requires knowledge of the underlying RDBMS support, for example they need to create indexes, foreign key constraints, and are also restricted by the limits on names for schema objects.

> c. They are easier to use than SQL queries.

This option is not true because ease depends heavily on familiarity. A developer who writes raw SQL every day will find it a lot easier to write raw SQL queries compared to using the DDL classes.

> d. They prevent module conflicts.

The DDL classes have no knowledge about modules, so this option also is not true.

Answer (score -1):

**After researching and study I found that answer of this was option C.**

Because in Magento 2 this DDL script allow us to do operation with systematically
available function which are easier than SQL Queries.

And other above 2 options A. and B. are not related to DDL.

And also option D. is that there relation module conflicts because DDL is related to Database only.

Comment: Hi Satish,can you share that link where u got that answer

Comment: Not true. How easy something is for someone is subjective. It mainly depends on familiarity. Simplicity on the other hand is objective, but that is not part of the option.

Comment: Hello Vinai If I am not true then can you give objective answer.So It can be helpful to me and all developers also and  will appreciate your answer.